# Is it unhealthy to eat too much proteins?

Tags: nutrition, proteins

I've heard body builders take a lot of proteins so that they can build their muscles.  Since taking too much certain nutrition can generally cause health problem (e.g. carbo-hydrates, salts, etc...), I thought the same goes for proteins too.  So here comes my question:

1. Can eating a lot of proteins cause damage to your health?
2. Does this mean body builders who take a lot of proteins risk their health to build their muscles?
3. Or, does the threshold of amount of eaten proteins which can be a risk for health depends on how much they are consumed to build muscles?

Comment: You may want to use a search engine and type in something like _site:gov high protein diet "systematic review"_ and tell here what have you found.

Comment: Blood test for BUN will show above normal if one gets too much protein .

Comment: Institute of Medicine recommends between 10-35% of energy for protein. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK56068/table/summarytables.t5/?report=objectonly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Humans need between 6 to 10 percent of calories to come from protein. Six percent is almost enough for anyone. Ten is for pregnant women and hardcore athletes. To answer this question, it is important to state that animal and plant protein effect humans in different ways.

1. Yes. Consuming over 10% of calories from strictly animal protein has been proven to promote cancer growth. For the latest evidence-based information and a detailed report on this, read Chapter 3 of the book The China Study Revised and Expanded Edition.
2. Yes. Too much animal protein can cause kidney hyperfiltration while plant-based protein doesn't. ([1](https://nutritionfacts.org/video/how-not-to-die-from-kidney-disease/))
3. Humans need between 6 to 10 percent of calories from protein. Getting more than 10% of calories whether from animal or plant protein is not necessary. Consuming more than 10% of calories from protein is not only unnecessary, but it robs us of the space and opportunity to get calories from other nutrients that we need.

Comment: Also protein toxicity